# do while loop not working as expected

Tags: php, do-while

I am trying to fetch the XML data through the API and then add that xml data into database. Single API request fetched 50 results at a time, then for next 50 result i have to add page-num=2 or so on according to last fetched.

Everything is working fine except the do while loop that i am confusing with. Take a look on what i have tried:

```
// Main Call 
function call_to_cj($import_id) {

        flush();
        ob_flush();
        do{
            // Get Last Fetched Page
            $Last_Import = $this->CI->import->get_last_fetched($import_id);

            // Insert Product with foreach loop
            $Product = $this->insert_response($this->prepare_request($import_id, $Last_Import));

            // This should work after returning the $Product with 
            // $this->insert_response($this->prepare_request($import_id, $Last_Import));
            if( $Product !== FALSE ) {

                //$Last_Import = $Last_Import + 1;
                //$this->CI->import->update_last_fetched($Last_Import, $import_id);
            }
            else {
               exit( json_encode(array("status"=>"y")) );
            }

            //echo $Last_Import . "<br>";

            flush();
            ob_flush();
            sleep(3);

            //exit();
        } while( $Product !== FALSE );    // Stop if Product return FALSE

    }
```

As you see in

```
if( $Product !== FALSE ) {

    //$Last_Import = $Last_Import + 1;
    //$this->CI->import->update_last_fetched($Last_Import, $import_id);
}
```

This part should work after getting the value from `$Product = $this->insert_response($this->prepare_request($import_id, $Last_Import));` and `insert_response()` method also have a foreach loop.

```
// $data is coming through $this->prepare_request($import_id, $Last_Import) 
// which is fine just a request to API and Return the XML Result

function insert_response($data) {
        $attributes = $data->products->attributes();
        $Records_Return = $attributes->{'records-returned'};

        // Data Loop
        foreach ($data->products[0] as $product)  {


                $p_name = strip_tags($this->clean_xml_response($product->name));
                $p_description = strip_tags($this->clean_xml_response($product->description));
                $p_url = urldecode($this->clean_xml_response($product->{'buy-url'}));
                $p_manuf = strip_tags($this->clean_xml_response($product->{'manufacturer-name'}));
                $p_image = urldecode($this->clean_xml_response($product->{'image-url'}));
                $p_adid = $product->{'ad-id'};
                $p_price = $product->price;
                $p_saleprice = (string)$product->{'sale-price'};
                $p_currency = (string)$product->currency;
                $p_stock = $product->{'in-stock'};
                $p_msrp = empty($product->{'retail-price'}) ? "" : $product->{'retail-price'};
                $p_cat = $this->clean_xml_response($product->{'advertiser-category'});
                $p_isbn = empty($product->isbn) ? "" : (string)$product->isbn;
                $p_sku = empty($product->sku) ? "" : (string)$product->sku;
                $p_upc = empty($product->upc) ? "" : (string)$product->upc;


                $Category_Id = $this->CI->import->check_category($p_cat);

                // Check Category
                if( $Category_Id === FALSE ) {

                    $stmt_c = "insert into {CI}categories (category_name) "
                            . "values( ? )";
                    $this->CI->db->query( $stmt_c, array($p_cat) );

                    $Category_Id = $this->CI->db->insert_id();
                }


                // Insert Product
                $stmt_p = "insert into {CI}products (p_name, p_description, category_id, store_id, link, link_id, manf, tags, "
                        . "image, p_price, p_msrp, p_sale_price, p_currency, p_country, p_stock, p_isbn, p_sku, p_upc, unique_key, import_id) "
                        . "values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                $this->CI->db->query( $stmt_p, array(
                    $p_name, 
                    $p_description, 
                    $Category_Id, 
                    $Store_Id, 
                    $p_url, 
                    $p_adid, 
                    $p_manuf, 
                    '', 
                    $p_image, 
                    $p_price, 
                    $p_msrp, 
                    $p_saleprice, 
                    $p_currency, 
                    '', 
                    $p_stock, 
                    $p_isbn, 
                    $p_sku, 
                    $p_upc, 
                    $unikey, 
                    $this->import_information['import_id']
                ) );


                $Product_Id = $this->CI->db->insert_id();

        }


        // Through away if no more result founds
        if( $Records_Return < 50 ) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else {                
            return TRUE;
        }

    }
```

Now the Problem is, My `$Last_Import` not updated 1 by 1, after getting the result by the above method, its continuously increasing. Like if i have 60 Request in the API Request the the do while should work only 2 times, because 1 API request only returns 50 records.

Has i missed something? or doing something wrong? Please guide me with the right way.

Answer (score 0):

while looking at this portion of your source code:

```
if( $Product !== FALSE ) {
    //$Last_Import = $Last_Import + 1;
    //$this->CI->import->update_last_fetched($Last_Import, $import_id);
}
else {
    exit( json_encode(array("status"=>"y")) );
}

//echo $Last_Import . "<br>";

flush();
ob_flush();
sleep(3);
```

I noticed that the page is exiting before performing any flushing.
So the last valid product info could be getting skipped/not output 
as the page exits before finishing the operation.

I might suggest:

```
flush();
ob_flush();
if( $Product !== FALSE ) {
    //echo $Last_Import . "<br>";
    //$Last_Import = $Last_Import + 1;
    //$this->CI->import->update_last_fetched($Last_Import, $import_id);
}
else {
    exit( json_encode(array("status"=>"y")) );
}

sleep(3);
```